# I'm getting an error when writing an inputting in material form field

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm developping  a simple form in angular 2. I have a AddProfessorComponent that holds that form

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Professor } from '../professors.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-professor',
  templateUrl: './add-professor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-professor.component.css']
})
export class AddProfessorComponent implements OnInit {

  siap: any;
  name: any;
  nickname: any;

  professor = new Professor(123, "rola", "ro");

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {  }

  onSubmit() { }
}
```

and here's the html template for that component:

```html
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-title>Cadastrar professor</mat-card-title>

  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #addProfessorForm="ngForm" >
    <div class="example-container">
      <mat-form-field type="text">
        <input matInput #siap (ngModel)="siap" maxLength="7" placeholder="SIAP" name="siap" pattern="[0-9]{7}" required>
        <mat-hint align="end">{{siap.value?.length || 0}}/7</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field type="text">
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="nome" name="name" required>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field type="text">
        <input matInput #nickname (ngModel)="nickname" maxLength="12" placeholder="apelido" name="nickname" required>
        <mat-hint align="end">{{nickname.value?.length || 0}}/12</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>

      <button type="submit" mat-button class="button" color="primary" [disabled]="!addProfessorForm.form.valid">SALVAR</button>
    </div> 
  </form>

</mat-card>
```

When I insert any information into the input fields I get an error that says :

> AddProfessorComponent.html:13 ERROR TypeError:
>   jit_nodeValue_9(...).$any is not a function
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///ProfessorsModule/AddProfessorComponent.ngfactory.js:151:46)

Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ56a.png) of the error happening:

Does someone have any idea how do I fix this? I've searched everywhere.

Comment: Not sure if this is what is causing the error but your siap input is `(ngModel)` instead of `[(ngModel)]`

Answer (score 1):

Try following syntax:

```
<form #addProfessorForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addProfessorForm)">

  <mat-form-field type="text">
    <input matInput #siap="ngModel" ngModel maxLength="7" placeholder="SIAP" name="siap" pattern="[0-9]{7}" required>
    <mat-hint align="end">{{siap.value?.length || 0}}/7</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-button class="button" color="primary [disabled]="!addProfessorForm.form.valid"> SALVAR </button>
</form>
```

In such case of `ngForm` directive you need not to have `siap` on the Component. It is a part of `addProfessorForm`, so it will be available on submit as

```
onSubmit(addProfessorForm: NgForm) {
  addProfessorForm.siap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for  the answer but it didn't work out for me. The error is still showing up.